# Fast way to find a position of any unset bit in a memory buffer

Tags: c, linux

So I had an interview today, the question is:

> Given a memory buffer, find a position of unset bit
>
> int getPosition(const char *start, const int len)
>
> If all bits in this memory buffer is 1, return -1
>
> otherwise return an index of the unset bit, started from 0
>
> Performance is first priority

Example

```
start, len=4
0x00|0x00|0x00|0x00: valid return: 0 to 31
0xFF|0xF0|0xFF|0xFF: valid return: 8,9,10,11
0xFF|0xFF|0xFF|0xFF: valid return: -1
```

Update Example

it does not have to be the leftmost or rightmost bit, any position as long as the bit is 0 is ok

```
00000000|00000000 : valid return 0 to 15
10101010|10101010 : valid return 0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14
11110111|11111111 : valid return 11
```

And my answer was

```
int getPosition(const char *start, const int len) {
    if(len<=0) return -1;
    int i;
    char *p;
    for(i=0;i<len*8;i++) {
      p = start + i/8;
      if(((*p) & (1<<(i%8)) == 0) return i; 
    }
}
```

but the interviewer said you have to loop many times if the last bit is 0, can you improve it?

I really do not know how to.

Comment: how about checking for `0xff`/`-1`?

Comment: the example looks strange -- *any* position of an unset bit is ok?

Comment: You can use a `XOR` on each byte to check if a bit is unset

Comment: Not directly related, but your code assumes that `sizeof(int) == 8` which is not necessarily true.

Comment: I don't understand the examples, what should the return value be for the first example? Could it be any value from 0 to 31?

Comment: There are 2 duplicates now. One is for "first bit set", you just need to swap the conditions for "first bit not set"; the other for first bit not set.

Comment: @FelixPalmen yes, it does not have to be the leftmost or rightmost unset bit,

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to test every single bit in a `char` that has all bits set, it will compare equal to `(unsigned char)-1`. With that and also taking into account that a `char` could have more than 8 bits, the following code should do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

const char test[] = { 0xff, 0xf0, 0xff, 0xff };

long getpos(const char *buf, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if ((unsigned char)buf[i] != (unsigned char)-1) break;
    }
    if (i == len) return -1;

    unsigned char x = buf[i];
    int bit = 0;
    while (x&1)
    {
        x >>= 1;
        ++bit;
    }
    return CHAR_BIT * i + bit;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%ld\n", getpos(test, sizeof test));
}
```

Comment: not strictly conforming! you should use `unsigned char`.

Comment: You mean for the shifting? indeed ...

Comment: `char` could be signed and not have 2's complement representation.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yes, some `unsigned` make it robust for even exotic platforms.

Comment: How about `11010111`, it should return 3 or 5

Comment: @vego so? [it does](https://ideone.com/ytJ8JX).